# How to download an image only if it's not existing already?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, webclient, memorystream

I am writing a program that displays `usercontrols` in a `flowlayout` panel. The user layout has images, which are downloaded by the program.

For speeding up, the program should check, if the image to download already exists at the download location. If it exists, it may not download it again.

I am using this code.

```
WebClient wcGreatest = new WebClient();
Uri url = client.GetImageUrl(client.Config.Images.PosterSizes.Last(), searchSerie.PosterPath);
byte[] imageData = wcGreatest.DownloadData(url);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
seriePopular.btnSerie.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);    
stream.Close();
```

Comment: you realise that a file could have the same name, but newer or older than what you have in place and also be different.  the existence of a name check alone is flawed and wont give you much help.  But if thats the way you want to go you will need to invoke the DirectoryInfo class and then run a search for the files, or fun a check of `File.Exists(Path.Combine(myfilepath, myfilename))`

Comment: Is there any way to know the original name of a file you download using the WebClient when the Uri doesn't contain the name?

Comment: only if you were able to ftp and then look at the directory that its in, other than that you'd need to know the name of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists(pathPoster + fileName))
                        {
                            seriePopular.btnSerie.Image = Image.FromFile(pathPoster + fileName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Uri url = client.GetImageUrl(client.Config.Images.PosterSizes.Last(), searchSerie.PosterPath);
                            byte[] imageData = wcGreatest.DownloadData(url);
                            File.WriteAllBytes(pathPoster + fileName, imageData);
                            seriePopular.btnSerie.Image = Image.FromFile(pathPoster + fileName);
                        }
```